# Cocos2d menuitem mouse touch event?

Tags: cocoa, cocos2d-iphone, menuitem

Now I want the menuitem to call the touch delegate , but when I set the isTouchEnabled is yes and some delegate methods , but when I touch or move on the menuitem , it didn't work ,why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may be a stupid point but make sure ur calling istouchenabled on a cclayer and not a scene.

Comment: so what I want to do is when I touch the menuitem , how to response the touch delegate: just like ccTouchesMoved,ccTouchesBegin,etc,Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

you must make sure no other CCNode cover the menuItem that you want to touched,because something the visible of some CCNode is false,so which may cover the menuItem.if so,you should make the index(z property) of covering CCNode less than the menuItem.wish this words help  you,thanks!